# What meta tags to include on a modern website?

Tags: html, meta-tags

Currently all I have on each page is `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`. Do people still include meta tags like keywords, description, and author? If so, should they go on every HTML page or just the home-page?

Comment: You shouldn't even need that meta tag. Ideally, that should be a HTTP response header instead.

Comment: The charset should be explicitly defined, but you're right the HTTP response header supplies the content-type

Comment: @Tom: That's not quite right. You don't need the meta tag we're talking about at all if you specify a HTTP response header like this `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`. In any case, it would be better to have it all either as (preferably) a response header *or* (if that's not possible) as a meta tag - don't split it up between the two. Also, you should have started that previous comment with `@thirtydot`, so I get a [comment notification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you defiantly should have the meta charset

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

The http-equiv is not needed because it represents the HTTP header equivalent. For the web however the Content-Type HTTP header supplied via the web server (probably apache) should do. You can override the server defaults via [.htaccess](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-htaccess-charset) or using the PHP header() function.

It is also not a bad idea to include

```
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
```

Paul Irish's html5 boiler plate also recommends using:

```
<!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) this if you use the .htaccess -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

[http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/#The-markup★make-sure-the-latest-version-of-ie-is-used](http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/#The-markup%E2%98%85make-sure-the-latest-version-of-ie-is-used)

```
<!-- Mobile viewport optimized: j.mp/bplateviewport -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

[http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/#The-markup★mobile-viewport--creating-a-mobile-version](http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/#The-markup%E2%98%85mobile-viewport--creating-a-mobile-version)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think keywords have any impact on the ability to find your site using search any more. If you're going to use a description, you might want to include it on every page as it will help search engines to display a more usable description than they otherwise might for that page. I don't think it would be worth developing a separate description for each page, use use the same one on all.  It wouldn't hurt to omit all of them, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags like Keyword , Description author used from a long time to tell search engine about the content current page.

Like a product website the description should be information about product and Keyword about the tags product have and Author is a book writer. it's help search engine like google to tell them what is content on the page.

their is no need of it but it's help to improve the SEO.